Unable to program the MCU through STM32 ST-LINK Utility
I encountered an error while programming my STM32 microcontroller using ST-Link Utility. The exact error message is "The ELF loader sector erase function fails." Can you help me troubleshoot this error?
I want to program the microcontroller through STLink Utility. I uploaded the hex file and configured the option bytes in STM32 STLink Utility.
However, I encountered some errors during programming:

14:09:15 : Flash mass erase:
14:09:17 : Some flash pages are write protected!
14:09:17 : Flash programming:
14:09:21 : The elf loader Program function fails.
14:09:23 : The elf loader Program function fails.
14:09:23 : Memory-Loader error
14:09:23 : Error occurred during program operation!
14:09:23 : Programming error @ 0x08000000!


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I want to program the microcontroller through STLink Utility. I uploaded the hex file and configured the option bytes in STM32 STLink Utility. However, I encountered some errors during programming:
14:09:15 : Flash mass erase:
14:09:17 : Some flash pages are write protected!
14:09:17 : Flash programming:
14:09:21 : The elf loader Program function fails.
14:09:23 : The elf loader Program function fails.
14:09:23 : Memory-Loader error
14:09:23 : Error occurred during program operation!
14:09:23 : Programming error @ 0x08000000!

FYI: Clarifications goes into the question text, not in the comments. @brhans helped you this time.

The error message tells you what is wrong directly:
| > 14:09:17 : Some flash pages are write protected!
|
You need to set the relevant option bytes to the correct value. I don't have a manual in front of me so I can't post a proper answer

This issue could also be related to your other question. If the device ID doesn't match the expected value, then such a programmer error wouldn't be out of the ordinary.

I agree with Velvet. @NidhiSayanja is this the same device and software as in the other question?

yes, it is a same device
